Which point on a hyperbola is closest to a circle
$$ \text{hyperbola eq: }\text{ }\frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{y^2}{4} = 1 $$
$$ \text{circle eq: }\text{ }x^2 + (y - 2)^2 = 4$$
I know how to find the smallest distance if I'm given a point. But here I need to find 2 points, which is leaving me kind of confused. How can I approach this? I tried labeling all of the points on the hyperbola (1st quadrant) as $\left(x_0,\sqrt{x_0^2 - 1}\right)$ and all of the points on the circle as $\left(x_1,\sqrt{4-x_1^2}+2\right)$.
Then I took the difference between the x coordinates squared and the difference between y squared, but I get 2 unknowns so I'm not sure how I can continue with differentiation. Will the closest distance always be perpendicular to the hyperbola?

Do you know about Lagrange multipliers?

You are going on the right track ! (1) You have to calculate the Distance $D$ between those two Points (2) Instead of Derivative , you have to take Partial Derivatives $\partial D / \partial x_1$ & $\partial D / \partial x_2$ (3) You then make those $0$ (4) Solve those Equations

Never heard of this. This is in my high-school textbook.

Is there any way to do this without partial derivatives? This is in my highschool textbook. Maybe I can assume some things that I don’t have to prove and then solve based on that?

In case this information is helpful, the polar coordinate equations are $r = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta}}$ (hyperbola) and $r = 4\sin\theta$ (circle).

"highschool textbook" doesn't really narrow things down.  "No partial derivatives" does narrow things down: it tells us that you aren't looking at multivariable calculus, only single variable calculus.

The point on the hyperbola that is closest to the circle is the same point that is closest to the centre of the circle. You've said that you know how to do this :)

Of course, given that the hyperbola and circle don't intersect.

Clever. This works for finding the closest point on any smooth curve to a circle as long as the two don't intersect. It's true because for a circle the normal through any point goes through the center and so can be seen as a special case of the more general common normal argument used in Rishit Garg's answer.

Note that the shortest distance between two curves is along their common normal.
Equation of normal at any point $P_1(x_1,y_1)$ on a hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ is $$\frac{a^2x}{x_1}+\frac{b^2y}{y_1}=a^2+b^2$$
Here $a=b=2$, therefore
$$\frac{x}{x_1}+\frac{y}{y_1}=2$$
Now, this line also passes through the center of the circle $(0,2)$
$$\frac{0}{x_1}+\frac{2}{y_1}=2$$
$$y_1=1$$
$$x_1=±\sqrt{y_1^2+4}=±\sqrt{5}$$
Therefore
$$P_1\left(±\sqrt{5},1\right)$$
Hence, equation of common normal is
$$\frac{x}{±\sqrt{5}}+\frac{y}{1}=2$$
Finding it's intersection with the circle $x^2 + (y - 2)^2 = 4$, we get the point $$\left(±\sqrt{\frac{10}{3}},2±\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\right)$$
Since we want to calculate the shortest distance, we take the point nearer to $P_1$, i.e.,
$$P_2\left(±\sqrt{\frac{10}{3}},2-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\right)$$
Finally to calculate the distance, we take the pair ($P_1$,$P_2$) that lie in the same quadrant. Using distance formula,
$$P_1P_2=\sqrt6-2$$

Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I didn't know that the shortest distance is along their common normal, though it does make sense.
